# Makefile conditional execution of command based on variable value

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Currently I'm working on a makefile where I want to execute a function based on the fact if the value is present in a predefined list.

```
test: VALUES=A B C
test:
   $(eval FOUND=$(filter $(VALUE),$(VALUES)))
ifneq ($(FOUND),"")
   $(call myFunction,arg1,arg2)
endif
# do other things...
```

Calling the make command as follows:

```
make VALUE=A test
```

But for some reason, the call function is never called.
My guess is that the FOUND value is only known by the shell, but I have no idea how to get the desired result.

I've tried not using the eval function, and using bash conditional function, but for the later, I cannot call the 'call myFunction' because this is only known by make itself.

Comment: Anything that is NOT indented by a TAB (or is indented with a TAB but is outside a recipe) is parsed by make when the makefile is read in.  Anything that IS indented by a TAB (and is inside a recipe) is not parsed until later when make wants to build that target.

Comment: As a general rule it's almost always wrong to use either the `eval` or `shell` functions inside a recipe.  You should only do that if you really understand make very well, and understand all the corner cases around expansion etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing `make` and shell syntax and confusing yourself mightily along the way.

I'm *guessing* you are looking for something like

```
VALUES=A B C
ifneq ("$(filter $(VALUE),$(VALUES))","")
   call=$$(call myFunction,arg1,arg2)
else
   call=# nothing
endif
test:
    $(eval $(call))
```

Embedding `make` functions in a recipe like this is dubious. Probably restrict yourself to shell syntax in recipes unless you know precisely what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

`ifneq ($(FOUND),"")` is executed at read time, the commands of the rules later. So it doesn't work.

But you can build a single conditional command (bash assumed):

```
test:
    # this example will not work because of bash + make script mismatch !!!
    FOUND=$(filter $(VALUE),$(VALUES)); [[ $FOUND != "" ]] && \
        myFunction arg1 arg2
```

The problem is the call of `myFunction`, because it seems to be a make function.

Comment: It is indeed a make function, so that is why I wanted a workaround in the first place.